# How to serve decrypted user data to a client if the client only has a session ID to be sent in a request to the server?

Tags: node.js, encryption

In a nutshell, how can I decrypt user content that was encrypted using the user's password upon a request to the server from the client, when the user only has a session ID to be sent with the request to the server?

Do I make the client store the user password like the session ID so it can be sent with the request, so the server can use that to decrypt the user's content?

I don't really have an idea how it's supposed to work, like, Standard Notes for instance, has you entering your credentials once, and then you can make as many notes as you want that will presumably be stored on their servers encrypted, and synced with other devices that are logged into your Standard Notes account decrypted. I. e., I don't have to enter the password every time to save a note, or to fetch all notes decrypted.

My guess would be that the server actually doesn't decrypt the data, but rather sends the encrypted data to the client, where the client locally stores the password, and decrypts the data locally, in the client? If that's the case, how do I store the password in the client then?

(This is technically a general, abstract question, but as an fyi, I'm trying to implement this with a Node.js server where (encrypted) user content is stored in JSON files.)

**EDIT**: Basically, from answers and other people I've come to understand that my understanding of cryptographic keys is wrong. So. Yes. Therefore the question is kind of wrong too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My guess would be that the server actually doesn't decrypt the data, but rather sends the encrypted data to the client, where the client locally stores the password, and decrypts the data locally, in the client? If that's the case, how do I store the password in the client then?

This is exactly right. Servers should not be *able* to decrypt data unless they have a specific need for it. The password is stored in the user's password manager, or failing that, in their brain.

The encryption keys are either derived from the password (using PBKDF2 or scrypt for example), or they are random and encrypted using a password-derived key.

Storing those keys depends on your client-side system. Ideally, it will integrate with the system's secure key storage (for example Mac Keychain, Windows PasswordVault, or Android Keystore), but the specifics depend on how your client is implemented.

Comment: Is there a way to store the cryptographic keys in a web browser (since that's what my clients are)?

Comment: The only browser-writable storage I'm aware of is Web Storage, which is not strongly protected if someone has access to the local machine. Ideally, you would store a session key there, that you use to encrypt a cookie that holds the actual expanded key.  Building this entire system in a secure way is likely beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer, but for more information see https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/35530/where-and-how-to-store-private-keys-in-web-applications-for-private-messaging-wi.